# How to get the name of the button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I want to put the name of the button in a variable so I can use it to know which button is pressed. I am making a few buttons at same time with my code. This piece of code is in a function so I cant use `var2[d2]` in another function.

```
for line2 in users4:
    parts2 = line2.split(";")
    parts3 = parts2[1].replace('\n', '')
    var2.append(c2)
    var2[d2] = Button(root, text=parts3, bg = 'black', fg = 'magenta', width = 4, height = 1, command = )
    var2[d2].place(x=e2, y=f2)
    c2 = c2 + 1
    d2 = d2 + 1
    f2 = f2 + 30
    if f2 >= 350:
      e2 = e + 62
      f2 = 5
```

So I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to access the button inside the callback associated by the `command` option of the button?

Comment: I want that when i click the button it makes a variable. that variable is then the name of the button. so for example, if i have a button with the text 'list 1' and i click the button, i get that button_name = 'list 1'